# How to set different options based on combination of positional arguments in Python with argparse?

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-interface, argparse

I'm trying to learn how to use argparse. I'm writing a program with two positional arguments let's say `ARG1` and `ARG2` and I want to add some options based on the combination of those two positional arguments.

The interface would look like this:

```
          D
          C
          B     B
          A     A
          ^     ^
          |     |
app.py <ARG1> <ARG2> --opt1 --opt2 --opt3 --opt4
```

The first positional argument `ARG1` would have 4 different options and the second positional argument `ARG2` would have two different options.
Based on the combination of those two positional arguments I want to specify different options.

For example, when the user enters `app.py A B` I want only `--opt1 --opt2` as required. Some combinations might not use some options at all.

I think `subparsers` is the way to go but I didn't manage to get it to work.

How can I do that?

Comment: A 'subparsers' is a kind of `positional`, but can only have one..  But your positional could each have `choices`.  Interaction with the optionals would have to be tested after parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Since `argparse` is designed to handle `optionals` in any order, it is awkward to force interactions.  Subparsers give some control, but can only have one (unless you define subparsers of subparsers).

I think the simplest is to define 2 positionals with `choices`, and all the optionals, and do any "required" checking after parsing:

```
In [20]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [21]: parser.add_argument('arg1', choices=['A','B','C','D']);
In [22]: parser.add_argument('arg2', choices=['A','B']);
In [23]: parser.add_argument('--opt1');
In [24]: parser.add_argument('--opt2');

In [26]: args = parser.parse_args('--opt2 foo C A'.split())
In [27]: print(args)
Namespace(arg1='C', arg2='A', opt1=None, opt2='foo')
```

A possible test:

```
In [29]: if args.arg1=='C' and args.arg2=='A' and args.opt1 is None:
    ...:     parser.error('--opt1 is required with C and A')
    ...: 
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--opt1 OPT1] [--opt2 OPT2] {A,B,C,D} {A,B}
ipython3: error: --opt1 is required with C and A
```

Keep in mind that it's hard to describe conditional interactions in the usage and help.  An alternative to requiring an `optional` is to give it a reasonable default.  That way it won't matter whether the user gives a value or not.  But in the above test, I'm depending on the default `default` `None`.

The usage shows the `optionals` first, and in the commandline `optionals` can occur in an order, with respect to themselves and the `positionals`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understood your requirement but see if this example helps you:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help="sub-commands")

a_parser = subparsers.add_parser("ARG1")

a_parser.add_argument("-1", "--opt1", action="store_true", required=False)
a_parser.add_argument("-2", "--opt2", action="store_true", required=False)
a_parser.add_argument("-3", "--opt3", action="store_true", required=False)
a_parser.add_argument("-4", "--opt4", action="store_true", required=False)

subparsers2 = a_parser.add_subparsers(help="ARG1-ARG2 sub-commands")

ab_parser = subparsers2.add_parser("ARG2")

ab_parser.add_argument("-1", "--opt1", action="store_true", required=False)
ab_parser.add_argument("-2", "--opt2", action="store_true", required=False)

b_parser = subparsers.add_parser("ARG2")

b_parser.add_argument("-3", "--opt3", action="store_true", required=False)
b_parser.add_argument("-4", "--opt4", action="store_true", required=False)

argument = parser.parse_args()
```

Output:

> ```
> ± % python recovery_tools/test.py ARG1 --help                                                 
> usage: test.py ARG1 [-h] [-1] [-2] [-3] [-4] {ARG2} ...
>
> positional arguments:
>   {ARG2}      ARG1-ARG2 sub-commands
>
> optional arguments:
>   -h, --help  show this help message and exit
>   -1, --opt1
>   -2, --opt2
>   -3, --opt3
>   -4, --opt4
> ```

> ```
> ± % python recovery_tools/test.py ARG1 ARG2 --help                                            
> usage: test.py ARG1 ARG2 [-h] [-1] [-2]
>
> optional arguments:
>   -h, --help  show this help message and exit
>   -1, --opt1
>   -2, --opt2
> ```

> ```
> ± % python recovery_tools/test.py ARG2 --help                                                 
> usage: test.py ARG2 [-h] [-3] [-4]
>
> optional arguments:
>   -h, --help  show this help message and exit
>   -3, --opt3
>   -4, --opt4
> (new-recovery-tools-env)
> ```